# Xcode simulator constantly download something

Tags: macos, xcode, xcode-simulator

Xcode 11.2.1 simulator 13.2.2 constantly download something daily about 450 MB through nsurlsessiond. Is this usual?

some logs

```
% sudo lsof | grep nsurlsessiond
Password:
UserEvent   60                   root  txt       REG                1,4      30016 1152921500312497946 /System/Library/UserEventPlugins/com.apple.nsurlsessiond.plugin/Contents/MacOS/com.apple.nsurlsessiond
nsurlsess  215         _nsurlsessiond  cwd       DIR                1,4        736                   2 /
nsurlsess  215         _nsurlsessiond  txt       REG                1,4     614448 1152921500312495196 /usr/libexec/nsurlsessiond
nsurlsess  215         _nsurlsessiond  txt       REG                1,4      28180            23592776 /Library/Preferences/Logging/.plist-cache.99GYDmPS
nsurlsess  215         _nsurlsessiond  txt       REG                1,4   29062064 1152921500312497147 /usr/share/icu/icudt64l.dat
nsurlsess  215         _nsurlsessiond  txt       REG                1,4   10833920            23596379 /private/var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n0000000000000/0/com.apple.LaunchServices.dv/com.apple.LaunchServices-1080-v2.csstore
nsurlsess  215         _nsurlsessiond  txt       REG                1,4    1558064 1152921500312496184 /usr/lib/dyld
nsurlsess  215         _nsurlsessiond    0r      CHR                3,2        0t0                 310 /dev/null
nsurlsess  215         _nsurlsessiond    1u      CHR                3,2        0t0                 310 /dev/null
nsurlsess  215         _nsurlsessiond    2u      CHR                3,2        0t0                 310 /dev/null
nsurlsess  215         _nsurlsessiond    3   NPOLICY                                                   
nsurlsess  215         _nsurlsessiond    5u    systm 0x1ebb302b93b87b91        0t0                     [ctl com.apple.netsrc id 7 unit 7]
UserEvent  311                 xxxx  txt       REG                1,4      30016 1152921500312497946 /System/Library/UserEventPlugins/com.apple.nsurlsessiond.plugin/Contents/MacOS/com.apple.nsurlsessiond
nsurlsess  345                 xxxx  txt       REG                1,4     614448 1152921500312495196 /usr/libexec/nsurlsessiond
UserEvent 8964                 xxxx  txt       REG                1,4      29984            23127670 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/UserEventPlugins/com.apple.nsurlsessiond.plugin/com.apple.nsurlsessiond
nsurlsess 9001                 xxxx  txt       REG                1,4     761744            23119545 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/libexec/nsurlsessiond
com.apple 9044                 xxxx    3w      REG                1,4   13597149            23603623 /Users/xxxx/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/F0685A70-DEB9-4786-8368-CF98BAC7FD1A/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.nsurlsessiond/Downloads/com.apple.mobileassetd/CFNetworkDownload_O3Y86b.tmp/AssetData/adat
xxxx@xxxx-iMac ~ %
```

this is launch_sim log

```
cwd
/
txt
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/libexec/nsurlsessiond
txt
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/dyld_sim
txt
/Users/xxxxxx/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/34D7CA2A-2595-4E6F-9622-2252E0BB5A08/data/Library/Preferences/Logging/.plist-cache.ouQB3E7W
txt
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/libobjc-trampolines.dylib
txt
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/share/icu/icudt64l.dat
txt
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDSSimulatorSupport.framework/IDSSimulatorSupport
txt
/Users/xxxxxx/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/34D7CA2A-2595-4E6F-9622-2252E0BB5A08/data/var/db/lsd/com.apple.LaunchServices-1080-v2.csstore
txt
/usr/lib/dyld
txt
/Users/xxxxxx/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Caches/dyld/19B88/com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-13-2.17B102/dyld_sim_shared_cache_x86_64
0
/dev/null
1
/dev/null
2
/dev/null
3
->0xe277ad83c16882a9
4
/Users/xxxxxx/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/34D7CA2A-2595-4E6F-9622-2252E0BB5A08/data/var/run/memory_warning_simulation
6
[ctl com.apple.netsrc id 8 unit 41]
```

this is sim log:

```
cwd

/

txt

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/sbin/launchd_sim

txt

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/dyld_sim

txt

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

txt

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib

txt

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib

txt

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib

txt

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib

txt

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib

txt

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib

txt

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib

txt

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib

txt

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib

txt

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib

txt

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib

txt

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/system/libsystem_asl.dylib

txt

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib

txt

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib

txt

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/system/libsystem_configuration.dylib

txt

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/system/libsystem_containermanager.dylib

txt

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/system/libsystem_coreservices.dylib

txt

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/system/libsystem_darwin.dylib

txt

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib

txt

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/system/libsystem_featureflags.dylib

txt

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib

txt

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/system/libsystem_m.dylib

txt

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/system/libsystem_malloc.dylib

txt

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib

txt

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib

txt

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/system/libsystem_sim_kernel.dylib

txt

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/system/libsystem_sim_platform.dylib

txt

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/system/libsystem_sim_pthread.dylib

txt

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/system/libsystem_trace.dylib

txt

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib

txt

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib

txt

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/system/libsystem_sim_pthread_host.dylib

txt

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/system/libsystem_sim_platform_host.dylib

txt

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/system/libsystem_sim_kernel_host.dylib

txt

/usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib

txt

/usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib

txt

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib

txt

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib

txt

/usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib

txt

/usr/lib/dyld

0

/dev/null

1

/dev/null

2

/private/tmp/com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.34D7CA2A-2595-4E6F-9622-2252E0BB5A08/launchd.log

3

[ctl com.apple.netsrc id 8 unit 38]

4

->0xe277ad83b83d2d29

5

/tmp/com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.34D7CA2A-2595-4E6F-9622-2252E0BB5A08/syslogsock

6

/private/tmp/com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.34D7CA2A-2595-4E6F-9622-2252E0BB5A08/launches.2019-12-10.20.17.19.log

7

/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.ylqXwtBNy6/com.apple.webinspectord_sim.socket

8

/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.ylqXwtBNy6/com.apple.webinspectord_sim.socket

9

/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.5cVa6VutSZ/Listeners

10

/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.26mpQitX06/com.apple.testmanagerd.unix-domain.socket

11

/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.5cVa6VutSZ/Listeners

12

/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.GjbwCBAvpU/com.apple.testmanagerd.remote-automation.unix-domain.socket

13

/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.26mpQitX06/com.apple.testmanagerd.unix-domain.socket

14

/dev/null

15

/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.GjbwCBAvpU/com.apple.testmanagerd.remote-automation.unix-domain.socket

16

17

/dev/null
```

**Finally i find a temporary solution!**

rename the file  com.apple.nsurlsessiond(Dont delete) in

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/UserEventPlugins/com.apple.nsurlsessiond.plugin/

to something -com.apple.nsurlsessiond

and also the file nsurlsessiond(Dont delete) in

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/libexec/

to something -nsurlsessiond

*Apps with admob works perfectly also no problem with safari*

Comment: When does this happen specifically? Every time: Xcode loads, you launch a new simulator,  you launch the simulator app or just daily at a specific timestamp?

Comment: everytime new simulator opens

Comment: It's happening to me now. Lol. I won't give a care to this but I just moved to a new house and I don't have a fiber connection here, but rather a limited data. It's quite a problem for me. Hopefully I find a solution soon.

Comment: Please take a tcpdump during this period.  After it finishes, collect a sysdiagnose and `xcrun simctl diagnose`.  Attach all three to a new radar (via Feedback Assistant).  Please report back the FB# here.

Answer (score 2):

While there's  an answer in the question itself, (renaming Xcode's internal

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/UserEventPlugins/com.apple.nsurlsessiond.plugin/

binary/ plugin), another way to solve this is firewall.

In system preferences  > privacy > firewall, Add Xcode to the list and block all connections.

If that doesn't stop it, download a firewall (like Little Snitch, LuLu) and block more processes.

- [Does Catalina 10.15 contact Apple servers when executing programs?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/393689/does-catalina-10-15-contact-apple-servers-when-executing-programs/393698#393698)

---

> The Simulators pane of
> Components preferences shows an entry for each optional simulator
> runtime. When an optional simulator is available but not installed on
> your system, Xcode displays a Download button beside that simulator
> runtime. Xcode can also be configured to automatically keep your
> installed simulator runtimes up to date.
>
> Download and install a simulator runtime: Click the Download button ()
> next to a simulator runtime.
>
> Check for simulator runtime updates: Click “Check and Install Now.”
>
> Install simulator updates automatically: Select the “Check for and
> install simulator updates automatically” checkbox.

https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/10.2/index.html?localePath=en.lproj#/deva7379ae35

[image]

Comment: Components pane shows old versions of simulators, I dont use them.

Comment: Uncheck the automatically option, as mentioned in the third point in the answer.

Comment: Still no effect

Comment: @VinuK.N Any update, how to resolve that issue?