# nsurlsessiond wasting my limited data plan

Tags: macos, ios, xcode, xcode-simulator

I am a cross-platform developer working on both android and ios platforms. For my ios development i used Xcode with ios simulator to make my work easy, and i got a new pc to work with. Whenever i tried to run Xcode with my build running on a simulator, the data is just flowing in and out like a river. I tried many things, and even removed the apple id and related accounts from my PC, but of no use.

`nsurlsessiond` takes on GB's and i dont know what it takes from me. Is there any way to get rid of this data eating monster so that i can work peacefully??

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) What is the version of macOS that you are running? Apparently some process is running in the background transferring data. Maybe macOS is downloading a update in the background.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61204523/how-to-stop-xcode-simulator-draining-network-data

Comment: @NimeshNeema I am on 10.15.3 . I haven't enabled automatic updates. It only consumes heavily when i opens Xcode/Simulator

Comment: @JeremyHuddlestonSequoia Unanswered! :-(

Comment: I know that the questions are not the same. But the solution is the same. If OP wanted to know _more about the process_ , I'd have voted for questions that try to make nsurlsessiond less opaque. But some weeks ago, I just decided to block it via a firewall.

Comment: @FortuneCookie The link Jeremy posted mentions this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59251235/xcode-simulator-constantly-download-something which has an answer with a workaround.

Comment: @jaume that exists on this site as well https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/377220/xcode-simulator-constantly-download-something/377266#377266